# A plea to consider "unclear" questions.

Tags: discussion

Some questions are so ill-defined that one has no idea what the questioner is asking, and it is reasonable to close such questions. In other cases, although the question is ill-defined, it reveals a muddle or misconception in the questioner's mind that can potentially be put right by careful explanation. In two recent cases, the question was of this latter type, and it was clear that the OP, although confused, was genuinely trying to resolve an imagined contradiction. I think that my answer, on each occasion, was a reasonable attempt to resolve the muddle. So it was disappointing to see that the questions were closed because "it isn't clear what you are asking". Of course the questions were not clear; what was clear was the misconception underlying them.

There is more to teaching mathematics than solving well-defined problems. Sometimes what is needed is to dissolve false assumptions and wrongly conceived ideas. We should not smack down people who are genuinely trying to understand just because their presentation is, necessarily from their inadequate state of knowledge, confused.

Comment: I looked at one of those questions. Personally I find the answers  rather might augment the confusion. I would answer something quite different in style. This shows, the site is not well suited for this. There is no doubt that there is more to teaching mathematics than well-defined problems. But this site is still for well-defined problems. It is not that end all and be all of teaching mathematics. It cannot be this. Over-stretching it is harmful.

Comment: In specific instances when this happens, you should feel free to post the question to [this thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19042/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-etc-volume-01-2015-current-versio) to help get it reopened.

Comment: Could you provide examples of what sort of questions you're addressing?

Comment: @quid: On the webpage describing what this site is for, the first listed item that the user is invited to ask about is "understanding mathematical concepts". The style of answers will always vary; it is up to the OP to pick the one that is most helpful. Perhaps your answer would best have resolved the OP's confusion. IMHO, it may be more useful to clear up a misconception than to supply the details of a calculation that the OP cannot do.

Comment: Yes, I agree, that conceptual questions can be better than computational ones. I still feel the sin(1/x) question is rather too vague. It would be good if OP included a bit more information what they understand and do not understand around the general matter. For example, do they understand that/why |x| is not diff'able at 0, do they not know any non diff'able function. Etc. The question is on hold, so that it can be improved.   The right way to 'consider "unclear" questions' is to help clarify them, not to add answers until one fits.

Comment: @MiloBrandt here is one http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1527146/why-cant-sin1-x-be-differentiated

Comment: @MiloBrandt: One question was "Why can't sin(1/x) be differentiated?". The other question was "Can anyone explain what *dual* means precisely?". The vote to close seems to have been reversed in the latter case.

Comment: The "dual" question *never* was closed.  At the moment is has one vote to close, as "too broad" not as "unclear." It is possible it had votes to close that aged away or were redacted. But in any case the question was never closed as unclear, or otherwise.

Comment: @quid: Probably the OP is too ignorant to elucidate what he does and does not understand. He thinks he does understand the issue, but is baffled that his understanding conflicts with what he has been told. Perhaps he thinks that differentiation is a formal operation on formulae; and, if the definition of the function can be arbitrarily extended at a tricky point, the same must be true of the derivative. Anyway, from my experience, it doesn't help to dwell on a student's confusion; rather, it is best just to explain the matter afresh from a clear perspective.

Comment: A  problem with sin(1/x) qis not  OP's math confusion, but the question is "lazy" and thus unclear. "I've read in textbooks that sin(1/x) can't be differentiated because it oscillates too rapidly,[...]" No matter how confused  about differentiability they ought to be able to give the textbooks  and/or an exact reference or quote. Chances are it did not really say just this, or not even this at all (indeed sin(1/x) is a peculiar example for a non-differentiable funct). Just rereading what it actually says might clear up the matter, and if not will result in a more clear question.

Comment: I think this question ties into the idea of multiple answers on very similar questions, e.g. this http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19115/what-do-we-do-with-so-many-similar-combinatorics-questions] and others.
There's a fine line between an OP post that is unclear and requesting merely an answer and an OP post that is unclear and requesting the background, which potentially could stem a hundred more questions that could be aided by the concept, if OPs searched hard enough for conceptual answers.

Comment: I've had trolls down-vote my [Answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1482443/derivative-of-expz) simply because I made some assumptions in order to provide a helpful response.  This is especially harmful because it encourages people to delete Answers that might actually have been helpful.

Comment: People who vote to close a question as "unclear" ought to first ask themselves whether the question might conceivably be more clear to someone with a different background. I answer a lot of questions about the mathematics of computer graphics. This is a fairly narrow niche, and is probably not familiar to the average math prof. In numerous cases, I see questions in this area branded as "unclear" when I'm pretty sure what they're asking. Annoying.

Comment: @bubba: I’ve also run into this phenomenon; not *very* often, but often enough to have found it a bit irksome.

Comment: @JerryGuern I don't know that it is fair to describe people who do this as "trolls".  The question should be clarified, either by the poster, or as an edit if it is 100% obvious what it *should* say.  The question and answer are taken as a pair when deciding how to vote, so if you have to make big assumptions in order to make the question "answerable", it is not a good answer to the question that is posted.

Comment: @MorganRodgers  So you're saying that if some student didn't know enough to specify EVERYTHING that should have been specified, we should refuse to attempt to help?  And if we make some reasonable assumptions about student-level problems so we can help, we should be down-voted and lose reputation points?  I don't buy that.  There's no good reason to down-vote a helpful answer to a poorly-asked question, particularly when doing so gets the helpful answer deleted.

Comment: @JerryGuern No, I'm saying we should engage them in the comments to clarify what they are asking, and get those changes edited into the actual question so that the pairing of the question/answer makes sense. Reputation points are minor.  It's not about taking away your reputation, it's about downvoting answers that are not likely to be useful to the community at large.  And of course, sometimes the *point* is for the low-valued question/answer pair to be deleted, if it cannot be edited or clarified to be of value.

Comment: As a teacher/tutor of many years, my inclination is to help, not nitpick.  If I refused help until students asked their questions with perfect clarity, we'd never get anywhere and they'd never learn anything.  Math SE exists so people can get help.

Comment: @JohnBentin  I just want to thank you for posting this.  This is a really important issue, and an upvote didn't seem sufficient.

Comment: @JerryGuern Sorry to be blunt. But your answers there were quite poor. You might consider that you were a bit out of your depth there. The down-votes were justified and it is a good thing those answers are deleted. *Trying* to help, is not always helping.

Comment: @bubba I agree that this is sometimes a problem. However, I would like to stress that to me there is a distinction between a clear question and a question were I am quite confident to guess what might be asked (or I can imagine several reasonable things that could be asked). I think in the latter case it is prudent to get the question clarified in some way.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott you might be annoyed by this somewhat less often when you start taking into account that for some "clear" and "I guess I know what is meant" are not the same. It annoys me when some users blur this distinction, especially when they do so with an attitude of superiority, implying that due to their expertise they understand the question while others do not. Indeed, sometimes it might just be the other way round, if all one knows is a hammer etc.

Comment: @quid: I was talking about unambiguously clear questions.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott That's fine. It is likely still a subjective notion though.  In any case I recall an occasion where you were pretty dismissive when I tried to get a poster to sharpen a question. (This while I did not even vote to close; I even answered them latter.)

Comment: @quid: I might add that *clear* versus *I guess I know what is meant* is far from being a binary distinction.

Comment: I tend to quickly vote "unclear" only when it is on a topic that has been handled many times here, or when zero effort has been made to give context. The worst are the ones dealing with different sizes of infinity, where young students come up with a barrage if imprecise language to justify their flawed intuitions about infinity.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I am not quite sure what you want to express. *Obviously* it is not a binary distinction. Indeed, I believe that for most (though not all) of the questions on this site that are clear it is also true that  I guess I know what is meant.

Comment: " There is more to teaching mathematics than solving well-defined problems. " Amen.

Comment: I really appreciate everybody who contributes here on the site, but as a low level math student I have to say that sometimes it seems like people just quickly skim trough some questions and readily vote to mark it as "Off Topic". I've asked multiple questions that were market as duplicates (even tough if someone actually read the whole question they would realize it was not) and the ruling never overturned. I've also had some questions where I admit I was a little unclear, but I believe with a little reading my confusion was clearly discernible and addressable; however, those questions

Comment: I know that lower level questions just do not get a lot of views, so marking them as off topic until further improvement is just condemning them to never being answered; and then I am stuck, I can't ask the question again because it would get marked as a duplicate right away, never be answered (because it's a duplicate) and be frowned upon.

Answer (score 7):

Who's to say that closing as "unclear what you're asking" isn't educational? Even if it's a bit...harsh, sometimes the message of "this is nonsensical" *is* important and educational. One of the biggest issues in learning mathematics is learning how to think precisely and clearly. It is easy to adopt "not even wrong" ideas at first, and sometimes it *is* necessary to correct this.

"On hold" isn't the worst thing that can happen to a question. Once the asker realizes that their question is nonsensical, and tries to reformulate it in an answerable way, it is not hard to take if "off hold".

Comment: I think that it is more helpful to say "The way to understand this is ..." than "You are confused; come back when you are not confused".

Comment: I agree. In the specific case linked it is mainly about "this is not precise and detailed enough." (not really nonsensical) OP scribbles a half-remembered sentence as something it says in textbooks. They should give the textbooks and an exact quote. (Or, not make claims about what it supposedly says in textbooks.)

Comment: Are we supposed to answer people's confusion on questions or just answer their question? It is ok to put on hold questions that demonstrate no effort on the part of the OP, but how is it helpful to just not answer a question if it is a valid point of confusion? I feel like this question is asking how to control "Tumble Weeds" in some sense, and not to just write off the generic OP as not being clear enough.

Answer (score -3):

When a question is tagged for deletion, we are given a list of reasons from which to choose to explain why it should be deleted. I think that, sometimes, we choose the unclear option because there is no "I think that this question indicates a lack of understanding so deep that there is no way I can help this person out" button.

Comment: While putting on hold/closure can lead to deletion it is not a necessity. The expressions "tagged for deletion" and "choose to explain why it should be deleted"  thus could be confusing, especially as there actually is a separate process to delete question that however does not involve giving a reason.

Comment: It looks as though the OP for the "sin(1/x)" question is turning out to be like that.

Comment: @JohnBentin it is never to late to vote to close :-)

Comment: "I think that this question indicates a lack of understanding so deep that there is no way I can help this person out." In that case, I feel like it might often be good to leave the question open in case someone else feels they *can* help the person out. Voting to close makes it harder for someone else to have the chance to help.

Comment: @MarkS. Of course you are right. I stand corrected.

Answer (score -7):

I totally agree with John Bentin. More precisely,

1. An analysis as to what are the cost-benefit of censorship on stack exchange might be interesting: Deleting an unclear question might make it easier to search but certainly discourages people from asking questions, particularly first time askers.  Improving such search engine as there might be would seem to be a better alternative inasmuch as, whether clear or unclear, a question always proceeds from a need or desire to understand.
2. Given that even perfectly clear questions are often misread, the grounds on which a question is closed are not always … clear. (E.g. compare the first sentences in the OP and in the avid19 answer.)
3. More generally, censorship is always dangerous, if only because power corrupts even censors. If only for that reason, I have never accepted to censor anybody, not even my own students.

Obviously, I am a first amendment absolutist.

Comment: You seem to have a very strange definition of "censorship"

Comment: @mrf he didn't read the [PSA](https://xkcd.com/1357/)

Comment: I have no idea where first amendment is coming into this. This is a private website that can do whatever they want. They can remove your posts solely because they don't like you and it won't be "censorship".